# Strange PHPCS error message

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I have the following snippet in a php class:

```
$returnArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rhandle)) {
    $returnArray[] = $row;
}
```

phpcs complains about the 'while' line:

```
 161 | ERROR   | Expected "while (...) {\n"; found "while(...){\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that cs (in this case) expects a space after the while. so you need to write your code like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rhandle)) {
}
```

EDIT: also, see that CS is reporting that you are missing the space between ) and { when closing the while, i think you fixed it when posting the question :)